# Not able to get location with mongodb geowithin and centersphere

Tags: mongodb, geolocation

I am try to get location within 5km radius of user coordinates, but every time i tried , it show me null .

Here below my code , am using for location.

```
const { latitude, longitude } = req.body;
```

```
const options = {
    location: {
      $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [[latitude, longitude], 10 / 3963.2] },
    },
  };
```

```
  try {
    console.log(getocationAre);
    res.json({
      msg: "data",
      size: getocationAre.length,
      data: getocationAre,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    res.json({
      msg: "Error",
      data: e,
    });
  }
```

Comment: For this purpose you should use `$geoNear`, not `$geoWithin`

Comment: @nimrodserok still not working

Comment: First: `10/3963.2` means 10 *miles* so about 16 km, not 5.  Second:  You have lat/long reversed.   Try `{ $centerSphere: [[longitude, latitude], ...`   Last:  `$geoWithin` is OK to use here.

Comment: so i have to change this in database also [longitude, latitude] ??

Comment: Yes!   Make sure you store your coordinate points as [long,lat] e.g. [x,y].  I am surprised you didn't get invalid data range errors upon insertion but there are obviously many coord pairs where interchanging long and lat *still* yields a valid (albeit wrong) location.
Reference: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/centerSphere/

Answer (score 0):

Since you have included *10/3963.2*, you are searching for something within 10 Mile. If there are no documents within that range, nothing will be displayed. If you want to search within 5Km of radius, include ***3.10/3963.2*** instead. If you wish, you can use this code which will help you to get the distance dynamically.

```
const radius = unit === 'mi' ? distance / 3963.2 : distance / 6378.1; /*6378.1 is for Kilometer*/
```

then,

```
{ 
  locResults: { $geoWithin: 
  { $centerSphere: [[longtitude, latitude], radius] } 
 }
}
```

Also, always use the Longitude first. I hope it will help you to solve the issue.